# Virtual audio device won't show up anymore (snd-aloop)

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, audio, pulseaudio, alsa

Archlinux on gnome `3.30`. Until the most recent update (`3.28` -> `3.30`) I used `snd-aloop` constantly to create a virtual sound device. After the update and a system reboot however it doesn't seem to work anymore.

When I do `sudo modprobe snd_aloop` or `sudo modprobe snd-aloop` the command exits with `0`. The output of `lsmod` shows `snd_aloop` too, however within `pauvcontrol` I can not select the virtual audio device. It's also not listed under the `Output devices` tab.

Since `lsmod` shows the module loaded properly I'm not sure where to troubleshoot either.

`pactl list short sinks` (and `sources`) don't show the virtual device either.

`alsamixer` shows `loopback` under `/proc/asound/cards` and it's in/out's under `/proc/asound/devices`. `/proc/asound/pcm` lists the virutal device too.

What's worth noting is that when I try to use alsamixer to change the volume controls of the virtual soundcard, it says `This sound device does not have any capture controls.` which I think is weird since there should be two (reg. input and monitor, both listed in `/proc/asound/devices`).

Logs are looking good to me:

[image]

Note that everything else is working fine with my sound and pulseaudio.

Comment: Argh! And of course, 2 minutes after writing and posting this question I fix it myself. A simple `pulseaudio -k` did the trick. If someone can explain why (I've never had to do that before) in the answers I'd still appreciate it.

Comment: The usual reason ALSA devices don't show up in Pulseaudio is if something else is using it (or was using it when Pulseaudio started). Restarting Pulseaudio solves that... BTW, you don't need to use `snd-aloop` if you are running Pulseaudio anyway, Pulseaudio has its own (more efficient) methods to do that, e.g. null sinks, recording from `.monitor` outputs, `module-loop` etc. I've tried `snd-aloop` once, and I much prefer the more flexible Pulseaudio way.

Comment: @dirkt You suggested PA's null sink module to me before and I've tried it with success, but it was using a lot more CPU time for me, that's why I'm staying with `snd-aloop`.